# in python virtual env mariadb_config command not found, without virtual env it works?

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm, mariadb, fedora

I use Fedora 32 WS, the system is freshly installed.I want to develop with PyCharm, I installed it via Flathub. I also have a Synology NAS with a MariaDB database, which I would like to reach in my development environment. With the Mysql Workbench this works. But if I start a new project in PyCharm with Python 3.8 and virtualenv and I want to install mariadb `pip install mariadb` I get errors:

```
Collecting mariadb
  Using cached mariadb-1.0.4.tar.gz (66 kB)

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/jonathan/PycharmProjects/RSSDB/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-dzg8lim2
         cwd: /tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/
    Complete output (17 lines):
    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: Command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/setup.py", line 26, in <module>
        cfg = get_config(options)
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/mariadb_posix.py", line 59, in get_config
        cc_version = mariadb_config(config_prg, "cc_version")
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/mariadb_posix.py", line 28, in mariadb_config
        raise EnvironmentError(
    OSError: mariadb_config not found.
    
    Please make sure, that MariaDB Connector/C is installed on your system.
    Either set the environment variable MARIADB_CONFIG or edit the configuration
    file 'site.cfg' and set the 'mariadb_config option, which should point
    to the mariadb_config utility.
    The MariaDB Download website at <https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/c/>
    provides latest stable releease of Connector/C.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

If I just execute the command `pip install mariadb` in my local terminal there are no errors so it seems to me that something is missing in virtual env.
Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Do following command before and after activating the virtual env

```sh
which mariadb_config
```

It could be that activating virtual env, removes the directory from the PATH when its activated.

If both report that its found and location is the same, then do check what

```
head -1 $(which mariadb_config)
```

If mariadb_config happens to be a python script, it might be that it has wonky shebang and you get "not found" error when running inside virtual env..

*EDIT*

According to the source here: https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-python/blob/master/mariadb_posix.py#L49

"Easiest" fix would be to:

```sh
export MARIADB_CONFIG=/usr/bin/mariadb_config
pip install mariadb
```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response.
mariadb_config does not seem to be a python script.
it can not be opened readable with a text editor.
Local: 
`[jonathan@linux ~]$ which mariadb_config
/usr/bin/mariadb_config`

In virtual env:
`(venv) which mariadb_config
which: no mariadb_config in ...`

Comment: Weird, what you describe feels like /usr/bin would be removed from PATH when you activate your venv..  You could try `PATH=${PATH}:/usr/bin pip install mariadb`

Comment: And looking at the path names, this feels like it could be caused by Pycharm.. Maybe there's settings to allow system paths still to be in PATH or something ... Never used pycharm

Comment: Yep, see my edit .. It looks like this: if you don't have MARIADB_CONFIG environment variable set when installing mariadb package, it will default to /usr/local/bin/mariadb_config but according to your which output, its actually in /usr/bin/ .. Sounds like a small bug in their python packaging ..

Comment: really many thanks, that solves the problem but there is a new one directly. My environment in PyCharm uses `/usr/sbin/` but the mariadb_config file is under `/usr/bin/` where it should be. Of course it all works if I use `export` to specify a different path but is that okay or would that be a mistake?
`/usr/bin/` in Pycharm Environment = `/usr/sbin/` on my local storage. This seems a bit suspicious to me.